# Java application server behind IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, java, iis-7.5

I have a Java application server (GlassFish, indeed, but the problem is the same for any other application server, I guess), running on port 8080. And I have IIS 7.5 listening on port 80 as by default configuration.

I want to avoid people typing the port because it's unprofessional. So I want that when somebody types

```
http://myserver
```

the traffic is directed to IIS. And this is how it already works now. But I also want that when somebody types

```
http://myserver/java
```

the traffic is directed to port 8080 and consequently my GlassFish splash screen is displayed. If I have deployed an application on GlassFish under context root `app1`, typing

```
http://myserver/java/app1
```

should access the application.

How can I do this? I have tried with adding some rules with the `URL Rewrite` utility from IIS7.5 UI, but this shows the port after the rule has rewritten the url, and I want to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

> **Update in 2018: Earlier Microsoft also created HttpPlatformHandler.**
>
> https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/httpplatformhandler
>
> So you should try HttpPlatformHandler at first. It is the magic behind
>   Azure's Java support.

You have several choices, but I recommend

http://tomcatiis.riaforge.org/

Microsoft's ARR is another approach but is heavier-weighted,

http://blogs.iis.net/mailant/archive/2009/10/22/how-you-can-use-iis7-as-web-front-to-java-app-servers-in-a-3-tier-architecture.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier if you can use a sub-domain for the java app like http://java.myserver/. Then you could do something like the following, though I'm not familiar with GlassFish but I assume you can configure it to listen on a certain IP address like with TomCat.  If you want to use port 80 for both apps you need IIS to listen on IP Address A and GlassFish to listen on IP Address B. Then use DNS to point myserver to IP A and java.myserver to IP B.

Then follow these steps: http://www.fredmastro.com/post/Restrict-IIS-to-listen-only-on-X-IP-Address-Allowing-you-to-co-run-with-TomCatApache-on-port-80-with-IIS-on-port-80.aspx

Basically limit IIS to only listen on IP A and not bind IP B. So that GlassFish can bind it to port 80.

> Open a command prompt as an administrator
>
> Show which IP Address IIS is listening/binding too with this command.
>
> `netsh http show iplisten`
>
> Then limit IIS to listen/bind certain IP address with this command
>
> `netsh http add iplisten xxx.xxx.x.x`
>
> Reboot the server (You could try
>   restarting http service but that doesn’t always show up in services
>   and it’s a pain. Easier to reboot).